# Can V=IR be applied to a short circuit?

Tags: ohms-law

Because on a short the voltage goes down while the current goes up, and a resistance of the line would be nill and remain unchanged. Does the formula fail or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, V=IR can be applied to a short circuit.

The most extreme form of a short circuit is a superconductor. The voltage across a superconductor is zero, regardless of the current flowing through it.

What you can't do is use I=V/R when R is zero, for obvious numerical reasons.

In practice, what most people call a 'short circuit' is just a very low resistance, for instance a spanner or short length of copper wire dropped across a couple of terminals. Here the resistance is finite, so we can do the calculation either way round.

When we are measuring a low resistance, we often use a Kelvin 4-wire connection, to use the V=IR definition, or at least the other inversion of it R=V/I, directly. We set up a current through the unknown resistance, then measure the voltage across the points that we want to define the resistance between. For very short wide conductors, the voltage measurement can get very close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

> Because on a short the voltage goes down while the current goes up, and a resistance of the line would be nill and remain unchanged ? So does this formula fail or am I misunderstanding something

A short circuit means that the impedance/resistance path of that (part of the) **circuit** is being **short**ed by a component or wire. The new impedance/resistance of that part of the circuit will therefore be lower.

So, the reasoning goes wrong by assuming: *resistance of the line would be nill and remain unchanged*

The voltage goes down due to the lower impedance/resistance and current goes up for the same reason.
V=IR has been changed because R has changed.

Answer (score -3):

The following is considering it in more details than the other (correct) answers.

If you are applying V=IR to an ideal voltage source (no interior resistance, voltage is constant), then on an ideal short (in the sense of zero resistance) the voltage cannot go down **by definition**. But in that case Ohm's law will always be an invalid approximation, because any wire has inductance (unless you manage to establish a short circuit with a zero length wire) and this inductance becomes more and more important if resistance gets ever lower. And as you might already know, an inductance is governed by the equation

$$V=L\cdot \dot{I}$$

So since that voltage source is able to maintain constant voltage, you will get a current that is rising at a constant rate

$$\dot{I}=\frac{V}{L}\qquad i.e. \qquad I(t)=I_0+\frac{V}{L}\cdot t$$

**So, yes, Ohm's law indeed fails in that specific understanding of a short circuit, but it does NOT fail in the naive sense, that current became infinite in no time.**

In reality there is a continuous transition between Ohm's (resistance) and Faraday's (inductance) regimes. If your voltage source has an interior resistance RS then you will get

$$V=R_S\cdot I+L\cdot \dot{I}$$

which, when you solve it as a differential equation, gives you an exponential function as the solution

$$I(t) = \frac{V}{R_S} - I_1\cdot e^{-t/\tau}$$

where the decay time tau of the exponential is given by

$$\tau = \frac{L}{R_S}$$

and the "amplitude" current I1 is given by your initial conditions, most probably by I(0)=0 and then

$$I_1=\frac{V}{R_S}$$

(see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL_circuit)). So only at practically infinite time in the future will you get the current you might have calculated prematurely by Ohm's law. However if inductance is low (as is the case for example for short breadboard wires), or resistance is high, "infinite time" can be reached very quickly.

By the way this is something you can measure very simply with an oscilloscope and a rectangular voltage generator, so it is not at all esoteric. For example if your wires have an inductance of 0.1uH and the interior resistance of your rectangle generator is 1 Ohm, you will notice the repeated 0.1us exponential curves on any decent contemporary oscilloscope.

Comment: Downvotes without a comment tell much about those who are downvoting. Especially when Wikipedia shows the exact same line of argument.

Comment: Here is another -1 with a comment for you. The Wikipedia article you've linked to has _zero_ relevance to the question in discussion.

Comment: @Maple: The OP was asking what happens on a short circuit. I wanted to give deeper insight into what really happens in the presence of the inevitable wire inductance. The Wikipedia article was cited just for reference of the calculation which I consider pretty relevant. But if "vote punishment" is considered appropriate on EE StackExchange for people who want to help and share their knowledge then it is no surprise that there is so little traffic here.

Comment: You postulate that "any wire has inductance" and yet ignore the fact that it also has resistance, however small it is, not to mention the internal resistance of the power source. That was invalid assumption by the OP and instead of correcting it you declared Ohm's law a failure. I don't think spreading this kind of "knowledge" is beneficial to thousands of people visiting EE daily.

Comment: Maple, I honor your willingness to discuss what you feel as being shortcomings of my answer. But one can hardly deny that this is remaining pretty unconstructive, especially when I see you quoting the word knowledge. It actually is common knowledge and I suppose you know that given that you have reasonable reputation. So I frankly don't understand why you think you have to defend territory or something along these lines. If you don't like other volunteers around you, then this is apparently a good place to be. At least you seem to have two fellow haters you can share your emotions with.